# Rotas Node.js com Angular.js

Tags: node.js, angular-routes

Estou começando agora no desenvolvimento com node e me veio a seguinte dúvida: muito se fala sobre a `mean stack`, mas como fazer o mapeamento das rotas utilizando node e angular? Qual deles vou utilizar para fazer as rotas? Poderiam dar um exemplo? Sendo que com os dois há a possibilidade de fazer chamadas dos métodos. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Em `MEAN Stack` `Mongo` é usado para gravar as informações, `NodeJs` para o back-end, express para ajudar no desenvolvimento `Nodejs`, e `angularJs` para o front-end, ou seja, o angularJs irá cuidar do gerenciamento das rotas, e o node irá somente mapeá-las, para devolver o resultado de acordo com a rota, exemplo...

**Build com express**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
app.use(bodyParser());

var porta = 3412;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || porta, function(){
    console.log('Servidor online porta ' + porta);
});
```

**Mapeando as rotas**

```
app.get('/nomeDaRota', function(req, res) {
  res.json(restaurantes);
});

app.get('/nomeDaRota/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    for (var i = 0; i < objeto.length; i++) {
        if (objeto[i].id === parseInt(id)) {
                var peg = objeto[i];
        }
    }

    if (typeof peg == "undefined") {
        res.json('Erro');
    }else{
        res.json(peg);
    }

});
```